# Почему стоит отказываться от HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: java, android, http

Был сегодня на интервью.Ответил на все вопросы ,но вот на один они сказали ответ не правилен .Было задание подключиться к `web-services` ну и там по апи сделать разные дейтсвия.Всё окей только отметили что для этого я использовал HttpUrlConnection и сказали лучше найти ей альтернативу .Ясное дело я не смог у них спросить почему)Так вот, чем плох `HttpUrlConnection` и что посоветуете в замен.И почему

Comment: Он достаточно многословен и не то, чтоб удобен в использовании. Скорее всего они хотели увидеть какой нибудь модный `Retrofit2`  или, хотя бы, `okhttp`

Comment: @rjhdby я тоже склонен к этому может им тертофит былоб сделать )но опят таки ретрофит помоему сам в основе использует httpurlconnection

Comment: @elik неверно. Retrofit просит выдать ему OkHttpClient, которому он делегирует всю работу с http. OkHttp использует сокеты (за исключением отдельного okhttp-urlconnection).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы не стал за использование `HttpUrlConnection` бить по рукам. Просто это более низкоуровневый механизм. 
Вам необходимо заботиться о многих вещах самому:

1. Необходимо оборачивать это дело в `AsycnTask`.
2. Хендлить случаи со сворачиванием игры.
3. Обрабатывать повороты экрана.
4. Писать кеш свой.

Тот же Retrofit из коробки будет быстрее, так как там встроенный механизм кеша.

Поэтому и рекомендуют volley/retrofit использовать. Уменьшается вероятность ошибки, меньше кода писать. Код читабельней и т.п.

Но, опять же, лично я бы не стал за ответ с использованием `HttpUrlConnection` минус ставить.

Comment: Кеш в OkHttp, не в Retrofit.
У HttpUrlConnection встречается несовместимость с некоторыми серверами.

Comment: @DeKaNszn какого рода несовместимость? о_О

Comment: обычно с SSL. до андроида 4.4 ещё было несколько багов, которые сейчас уже почти неактуальны

Comment: @DeKaNszn вы про поддержку различных ciphers?